# onListItemClick is not getting called on ListActivity

Tags: android, android-imageview, listactivity

I have a small application, and I am trying to display list of youtube thumbnails using the ListActivity

```
public class ResultListActivity extends ListActivity {
.....

......
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

loadData();


---
---

}


private void loadData(final String searchQuery) {
        AsyncTask<Object, Void, List<YouTubeVideos>> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Void, List<YouTubeVideos>>() {

.....

}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override  
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {  
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

        Log.d("test","Inside onListItemClick");

}
```

The xml looks like this

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>



   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    >
</ImageView>
```

Adapter:

```
public class ResultViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(torvideo.getDrawable());





        return row;
}

...

}
```

I am not able to get the onListItemClick  invoked.  Could you please let me know if I am making any mistake?

Update 1/17

When I click nothing happens but I see these in logs

01-18 04:09:32.030: W/Trace(973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Comment: Seems it is because you have an ImageView in the List. Try changing it to normal textView and check if event is getting handled?

Comment: No, its not getting called even for textView

Answer (score 3):

In my `ListView` I have an clickable `TextView` and clickable `ImageView`. `onListItemClick` didn't work for me since I have more than one clickable items in the list row. So what I did is i implemented `onClickListener` in my `getView()` for the adapter.  Here is my code:

```
public class SimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private String[] mStrings;
private TypedArray mIcons;
private int mViewResourceId;

public SimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] names, TypedArray icons) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, names);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mStrings = names;
    mIcons = icons;
    mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}


public int getCount(){
    return mStrings.length;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
    iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));
    iv.setTag("colorChooserClicked");

    iv.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        int pos = position;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("text", "Image clicked, row %d"+pos);

        }
    });
    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview01);
    tv.setText(mStrings[position]);
    tv.setTag("textViewClicked");
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        int textpos = position;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("text", "Title clicked  %s"+mStrings[textpos]);
        }
    });
    return convertView;

}

}
```

It happens since we have more than one clickable item and we are trying to use the `ListActivity`. Else the other option is to extend `Activity` class for your `MainActivity` and then do it.

Answer (score 2):

For ListActivity its simple to call `setOnItemClickListener`

The corresponding code is below

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int position, long arg3)
{
   System.out.println("LIST ITEM POSITION "+position);
}
});
```

Comment: Added this in my ResultListActivity after the load() method.  Still no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

> your imageview xml of baseadapter add this line

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: Added this, but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = getListView();
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                     Log.d("test","Inside onListItemClick");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));` in your ResultViewAdapter for getView()

Comment: OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type. compilation error

Answer (score 0):

if you have a class called ListActivity make sure you are extending from the right listActivity because when extending, both your class ListActivity and the super class ListActivity will show up