# onListItemClick is not work for custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick

Trying to create a click handler for the ListView, but the list does't respond to clicks.
Read many of the local responses, but nothing helps for me :(

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockListActivity {

private ArrayList<Order> listItems;
private myAdapter myAdapter;
ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
this.myAdapter = new myAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, listItems);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
....
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked " + l.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
}
```

Layouts
Main:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="#000000" >
</ListView>
```

rows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Название"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Эпизод, время"
    android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Thanks for your help.
Regards

Comment: have you  buttons inside list_item?

Comment: No buttons, only 2 textview and 1 imageview

Comment: are those clickable or focusable? I recall a similar issue. try putting android:focusable="false"

Comment: post the entire XML layout please.

Comment: try to put toast message above super method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setOnClickListener in your adapter. OnListItemClick will not work since you have ImageView. [onListItemClick is not getting called on ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373527/onlistitemclick-is-not-getting-called-on-listactivity)

Comment: Thanks, it work. I knew that in `getView()` will work, but I want to implement this in `MainActivity`. But I did not know that it prevented  images. Thankf for useful info

Answer (score 2):

if you want your class to respond to the event, your class must implement OnItemClickListener, and then assign it to your list list.setOnItemClickListener (this);