# list activity onListItemClick does not firing

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listactivity

I nedd to click on items in list activity to do something, but its not working
i search for this problem and saw some answers about this such as :

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

or

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

but those are not worked

this is my listActivity :

```
public class TrainListActivity extends SherlockListActivity
{
public static String varStart = "com.example.traininfo.startcity";
public static String varDestination = "com.example.traininfo.destinationcity";
private String start;
private String destination;

 ArrayList<TrainType> trains;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trainlist);

    Log.i("SearchTrain", "try to get extras...");
    start = getIntent().getExtras().getString(varStart);
    destination = getIntent().getExtras().getString(varDestination);

    TrainController tc = new TrainController(this);
    trains = new ArrayList<TrainType>();
    trains = tc.getTrainList(start, destination).getTrain();
    Log.i("SearchTrain", "got the train list...");

    TrainListAdapter adapter = new TrainListAdapter(this, trains);
    Log.i("SearchTrain", "adapter initialized successfully!!");
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

@Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
         // I want to do something here :(
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.i("trainList", "on click");


}
```

}

row xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#27ae60"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTrainName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/resultTrainName"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStartLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTrainName"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeOut"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimeOut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTrainName"
    android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvStartLabel"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeOutEx"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFinishLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvStartLabel"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeIn"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimeIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvTimeOut"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTimeOut"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeInEx"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTimeIn"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/resultMoreInfo"
    android:src="@drawable/action_info" />
```

and ListActivity xml File :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" />

</LinearLayout>
```

please help me :(

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you mean by "not working?" do you se the message that you have in onListItemClick in logCat?

Comment: means that 'onListItemClick' not called

Comment: How about removing focusable and clickable from the relative layout also?

Comment: not works in this way too

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem not too long ago. It seems that the `ImageButton` takes focus regardless what you do. What I did was to replace the `ImageButton` with and `ImageView` and set the listener to it.

This is how your xml files should look like.

row xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#27ae60"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTrainName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/resultTrainName"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStartLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTrainName"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeOut"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimeOut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTrainName"
    android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvStartLabel"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeOutEx"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFinishLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvStartLabel"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeIn"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimeIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvTimeOut"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTimeOut"
    android:text="@string/resultTimeInEx"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTimeIn"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/resultMoreInfo"
    android:src="@drawable/action_info" />
```

`Activity` xml.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the `ImageButton` and in its place put an `ImageView`. Switch back all parameters in the `ListView`  and other `Views` inside the row xml back to normal (i.e. remove all focusable attributes and all other stuff you added)

Comment: I updated my answer with how the xml code should be. Also, no need to create an xml that contains a `ListView` if you are extending `SherlockListActivity`

Comment: i do what you said but still not works , may be problems is with my emulator

Comment: i use genymotion , and im not testing these codes on a second emulator or an android phone :-/

Comment: try to set the adapter by getting a reference of the `ListView` via `getListView().setListAdapter()`

Comment: i change my code aanf now i am usin a sherlockActivity with custom listView

Answer (score 0):

Use normal activity and put a ListView in xml. Use inflator to use your custom row design. Just put the focusable=false for your imagebutton. It will allow you to click on the row and you can apply a separate click listener for your imagebutton to handle its click separately.

Comment: This seems not to work either. I tried this approach when I faced this problem. I ended up using an `ImageView` instead of the `ImageButton`

Comment: Have you tried using button in spite of your ImageButton. I never faced this issue using either of them.

Comment: How are you inflating your list row ?

Comment: I wanted to use `ImageButton` because it is simple to add an image to it. I am creating a `Class` that extends `RelativeLayout` and inflate the row in its constructor.

Comment: Better you use a list adapter. There seems to be some problem with you inflater class. You can add image to button as well in its background.

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: I suggest you create your own list by using listadapter. Don't use the   SherlockListActivity just extend by Activity. Put ListView in your xml. Give it an id like android:id="@+id/lv". Add items to it using list adapter.

Comment: If you want I can give you an example.

Comment: i have to use sherlock activity because i need it's action bar

Comment: are you talking with me or with the OP @CodeWord?

Comment: I just posted it for m.sharifi

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373527/onlistitemclick-is-not-getting-called-on-listactivity